# Index Match Using Wild Card References Issue In Reference Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to flag all line items in "array B" where a flag is assigned if there is a partial match in "array A". I would like to make the "flag" that is returned the cell found in "array A".

I am wondering whether or not Index Matching with a Wild Card reference is the correct way to accomplish this. I am pretty new to Excel formulas.

Please see below what I have already accomplished.

I have already tried multiple equations found on Stack Overflow, but they do not seem to address my issue. Please see below for the equation that I am trying to use.

view the screenshot of my file here: [image: https://i.imgur.com/DSrKfA0.jpg]

Here is the formula I am trying to use `=INDEX(B$1:B$9998,MATCH("*"&G2&"*",A$1:A$9999,0))`

I expected the contents of the "flag" column to return but instead, the equation returns value #N/A

**EDIT: I have included a simpler data set to use as an example below**

[View Simpler Data Set Here - Cant Post Images Yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaQR1.jpg)  - Edit to include if you can, thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain why do you need to use wildcards? Taking your first Variation as an example ("BER-92-MP-002"), what kind of match do you expect to retrieve from column A?

Comment: @JustynaMK I am looking to place the "Master SKU" next to each "Variation of Master SKU" in the array to the right (Column G). 

So my reasoning was that by using Index Match with a wild card reference (which I haven't been able to figure out yet- please note that I'm trying to accomplish this by using "*"&G2&"*" ) I could match the Variation Sku (column G) with the Master Sku (Column A).

Hope this information helps! Thank you for any input!

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I'll create an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your additional explanation. If you want to match the Variation Sku (column G) with the Master Sku (column A), I assume that you want to use wildcards because some of your variations (e.g. BER-92-MP-002) might slightly differ from column A (e.g. "xxxBER-92-MP-002xxx"), that is why you wanted to look for:

```
"*"&"BER-92-MP-002"&"*"
```

[image: table1]

Assuming this is correct, then you can use an Array formula to look for the Row number where the match occurs, e.g. cell E2 (Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=MAX(IFERROR(IF(FIND(G2,$A$2:$A$9),ROW($A$2:$A$9)),0))
```

Then your Flag can be retrieved as follows (cell F2):

```
=IF(E2,INDEX($B$1:$B$9,E2))
```

Screenshot with the final result:
[image: final result]

I hope it helps & apologies if I misunderstood your original request. Happy to adjust both formulas if necessary (you can post additional screenshots by editing your original post).

**Adjusted:**
Assuming that your search string always starts with "SKU" and is followed by "-" symbol and one additional string (e.g. SKU-BLUE), you can use the following formula in cell F2:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(MID(H2,FIND("SKU-",H2),FIND("-",MID(H2,FIND("SKU-",H2),100),5)-1),$A$1:$A$5,0),0)
```

Formulas in column G are the same as in my previous post. Final result:

[image: final2]

Comment: This does not resolve the issue but I appreciate your time @JustynaMK .

I included another screenshot link of what I am trying to accomplish, I hope this helps. Thank you so much for your input so far.

Here it is: [link](https://i.imgur.com/2mijGCs.jpg)

Comment: Also, please note that I updated my original post @JustynaMK , thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Please see my adjusted answer.